# Regex to find only one letter in a line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command

I have a doc that contains words that describes languages and i need to count how many times they appear in the doc, i have to match only C, C++, Pascal, Scheme y Ada. 
How can i implement it in one line like this:

```
grep (C++|Ada|Pascal|Scheme|C)
```

Comment: Each of the languages or all of them together?

Comment: your cmd won't work. can you show some content of your file? e.g. you don't want to count `Can you...` as a `C` language do you?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
grep -o 'C++\|Ada\|Pascal\|Scheme\|C' * | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a complex subject. You want to match `C` but avoid matching `ABC` or `Cookbook`, so you need to be sure you're only matching whole words (option `-w`). You also want to extract all the matches, not just the lines that matched, since you may have several matches in a particular line (as in your question for example) (option `-o`).

```
grep -w -o 'C\|C++\|Pascal\|Scheme\|Ada' file | sort | uniq -c
# or
grep -w -o  -e C -e 'C++' -e Pascal -e Scheme -e Ada file | sort | uniq -c
```

The `sort | uniq -c` will show you how may times each word appeared. If you just want the total for all the words, use `wc -l` as others have showsn.

Comment: A further thought: the pattern `C++` contains non-"word" characters (the pluses) so the `-w` test to match only whole words. For example the text `C++++` will match the pattern `C++`, and the text `C+` will match the pattern `C`